# Open a single element at a time

Tags: jquery

The solution should be simple but because of the markup, I'm getting thrown. Right now I have 4 identical sections on a page with the below markup. The problem is when "tag-trigger" is clicked they all open / close simultaneously. I want each to open / close individually.

```
<div class="tags">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="tag-trigger"></span></li>
        <li><a href="" class="guidance-note">Note</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Tag one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tage two</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tags-toggle-container">
        <li><a href="#">Tag 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tag 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tag 5</a></li>
    </ul>                           
</div>
```

And the jquery -

```js
$('.tags-toggle-container').hide();

$('.tag-trigger').click(function() {
    $('.tags-toggle-container').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

I can't figure out how to interact with "tags-toggle-container" on an individual basis. I think that if the markup was different then this would work but I'm afraid that changing it is not an option. I've looked at other solutionions but they all seem to reference .siblings or .closest.

```
$('.tags-toggle-container').hide();

$('.tag-trigger').click(function() {
$(this).find('ul.tags-toggle-container').slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the HTML you provided, you'll find the element like so:

```
$('.tags-toggle-container').hide();

$('.tag-trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).parents("ul").siblings(".tags-toggle-container").slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

This assumes that the `.tags-toggle-container` element is a direct sibling of the `<ul>` in which your `.tag-trigger` is located.

Comment: OK, thanks to all. This worked a treat. I'll look at the other solutions as well just to familiarise myself with them. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! Roland's solution is just as viable. Instead of the direct sibling relation, his snippet uses their direct parent to find eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Go up in the DOM tree to the closest `.tags` div and then down to the `.tags-toggle-container`:

```
$('.tag-trigger').click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".tags").find(".tags-toggle-container").slideToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just count up by setting a variable.

```
var i = 0;
$(function() {
    $('.tag-trigger').click(function () {
        $( 'ul.tags-toggle-container > li' ).eq( i++ ).slideToggle();
    });
})
```

I think you are after something like this.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LNC4/42/)

Comment: That isn't it. The problem isn't that he wants the tags to sequentially show themselves; but that if one button is clicked, ALL elements show/hide themselves instead of only the element that is related to the button that was clicked.

Comment: @Flater - Yeah, after seeing the other answers I realized I read it completely wrong! haha

Comment: Nonetheless, I learned something from your snippet. I find it quite elegant, barring the global variable :)